# String to Date gives wrong result

Tags: java, string, date

I have:

```
String t = "Sep 17, 2015 00:00:00"
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date date = format.parse(t);
```

What am I doing wrong here because everytime I try to parse I get an exeption.

Comment: You have the wrong format

Comment: What relationship does `Sep 17, 2015 00:00:00` have to `dd.MM.yyyy`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer dd.MM.yyyy is what I later want to have. I don´t need all the zeros.

Comment: Does that mean you'll accept my answer (despite the debate), looks like it was correct?

Comment: @HHH Okay, but first you need to transform the `String` value into a `Date` value, once you have the `Date` value, then you can format at in anyway you like.  `Date` DOES NOT have an a concept of format, it is a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch, so you can't make a `Date` with a predefined format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date fromat is wrong. change to:

```
String t = "Sep 17, 2015 00:00:00"
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse(t);
```

For more information see the javadoc of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

As i understand your comment right, you want a string in format dd.MM.yyy.

So you have to create a SecondDateFromat to format the string

```
DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String result = format1(date);
```

Comment: @Jens thanks for your answer. The reasen I used the wrong format was because I wanted it to be  my result. So althought I have the other stuff I my string later I just need it how I wrote I my question. Do you have any Idea how to do that?

Comment: @HHHH I can not get you. You mean you will reformat the date as a string in dd.MM.yyyy?

Answer (score 1):

The date and the date format don't match. You can change the date to match your format (or vice versa)

```
 String t = "17.09.2015"
 DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
 Date date = format.parse(t);
```

Comment: It doesn't say anything like that in his requirements, so in the absence of clear direction it could be either [You can change the date to match your format (or vice versa)] .

Comment: REALLY JOHN?? I wanted (with my comment) to encourage you to improve answer to get some upvote (mine first), now, you have my downvote...

Comment: Hi Jordi, can you point to the part that shows he isn't in control of the formating of the date input Strings? I can see a mismatch for sure, but there's nothing to indicate this isn't (for example) a school assignment where he can control the format of the Strings he is processing.

Comment: That's unfortunate Jordi, and I think a little emotional. @Rehman has answer with the format reversed. What would be the point of two identical answers? The code shows simply how to change the date to match the format he has.

Comment: There are plenty, a) is what OP written first in code b) you miss time with your example c) **a programmer does not change input never, adapt himself to match given data to output needs**

Comment: and please, check @Rehman answer, latter than yours but covering all possibilities, which **is completely valid** and don't hesitating to improve it with editing, not like you, using a silly code to get fast rep....

Comment: @Jordi I disagree strongly with this statement  -" a programmer does not change input never, adapt himself to match given data to output needs". Software engineering involves clearly defining interfaces, input types and boundaries. And that involves clearly communicating (and negotiating) what your inputs are with your stakeholders. My point is very simple here, in the absence of clear hard requirements either could be changed.

Comment: Hopefully we can agree to disagree then? I admire your passion for software development, and although I have a different view on this issue (I'm sure there are some we can find common ground on in the future)!

Answer (score 1):

When you are using "dd.MM.yyyy" as date format, your input should be 17.09.2015 instead of "Sep 17, 2015 00:00:00"
So you have two options : Either,

```
String t = "Sep 17, 2015 00:00:00";
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(t);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

or

```
String t = "17.09.2015";
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(t);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: and how you solve it if you cannot change the date because it comes from a file or form or whathever?

Comment: In that case format needs to be changed : "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Comment: @Jordi Castilla Edited my answer

Comment: @Jordi Castilla Thanks Buddy